# Bookmarklet to replace input values of random name input fields

Tags: javascript, replace, innerhtml, bookmarklet, getelementsbyname

I would like to create a bookmarklet that replaces all *values* of every input field on a webpage. There are a lot ot them but they can be split into two categories by their *name*.

Example:

```
<input class="Class1" name="ABC_randomnumbers" value="randomnumber" type="text">
<input class="Class1" name="DEF_randomnumbers" value="randomnumber" type="text">
```

Input fields with its names starting with ABC would receive the value X, input fields with its names starting with DEF would receive the value Y.
I tried

```
javascript:document.body.innerHTML=document.body.innerHTML.replace(/input class="Class1" name="ABC_(\d+)" value="\d+"/g,'input class="Class1" name="ABC_$1" value="X"'); document.body.innerHTML=document.body.innerHTML.replace(/input class="Class1 name="DEF_(\d+)" value="\d+"/g,'input class="Class1" name="DEF_$1" value="Y"');
```

to replace all occurences of these strings in the HTML but it messes up the whole page, for example it deletes the contents of the  tag.
I read something about *getElementsByName*, but they don't have the same name and I can't get regexp work with *getElementsByName*.

Comment: Have you tried using `getElementsByClassName()` or maybe use `querySelectorAll()`?

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` would't be good because there are two types of input fields, one with name *ABC_randomnumbers*, the other with name *DEF_randomnumbers* (also these numbers are different for every input field) and they have to receive different values. I haven't heard of `querySelectorAll()` though

Comment: For example if you want to use `querySelectorAll` to target all `inputs` that have **_randomnumbers** in the value for the `name` attribute you can use...  `document.querySelectorAll("input[name$='_randomnumbers']");`

Comment: Sorry, the `_randomnumbers` is really a string of random numbers generated by the back-end. It's different for every `input` field. Example:

`<input class="Class1" name="ABC_142315" value="634624" type="text">
<input class="Class1" name="DEF_512325" value="743534" type="text">
<input class="Class1" name="ABC_124156" value="525246" type="text">
<input class="Class1" name="DEF_141534" value="624253" type="text">
...`

Comment: Do you mean something like this [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/vrcmxvqj/)

Comment: If this could leave each input's name as it was and fill their values with 1000 for ABC and 2000 for DEF for example then this is what I'm looking for.

Comment: The name attributes are not being changed in that example. If  you want to set the value attribute to 1000 for all elements `ABC` and 2000 for `DEF` then you can simple add a if statement to do that. I am not 100% sure what your intentions are other than to find all input elements with the name ABC_****/DEF_**** and set a new value so I have used the randomnumber of each to show each input is found and able to be edited.

Comment: Example of the `if()` statement [**JsFIddle Demo - If Statement**](https://jsfiddle.net/vrcmxvqj/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would refrain from editing the base HTML in such a way. A better option is to edit the page with Javascript code. I provided an example below:

```
var allInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

for (var i = 0; i < allInputs.length; i++) {
    if(allInputs[i].name.startsWith("ABC_")) {
        //Do Logic here
    }

    //Other cases here
}
```

Shorthand version provided below:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("input")).forEach(function(input) {
    if(input.name.startsWith("ABC_")) {
        //Do Logic here
    }

    //Other cases here
});
```

Comment: How do I set the value of the input field from here?

Comment: @ventusz by using `input.value="something";` just like I have used in my **JsFiddle** Examples, only difference is I am using a different variable name `element.value=1000;`

Comment: I have run both this and the other code as a bookmarklet on the original page and although it changes the values that can be seen on the page but if I check with Inspector it didn't change anything. I have to submit this form with around 200 input fields but there are two values to go in all of them. There's no workaround from the server side unfortunately that's why I'm trying client-side.

Comment: @ventusz if you can see it changes the values on the page then it's doing exactly what you have asked for. You didn't say anything about changing anything in relation to those values or to trigger any other functions/submissions after changing. We can only go by the information and expectations you explain in your question.

Comment: @NewToJS It's working, case solved, I'm really glad for your help. You saved me a lot of time.